# Connecting a Multi Device Application to a DataSnap REST Server using FireDAC

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012, delphi-xe7, datasnap, firedac

I am using Delphi XE7. 
I have recently completed a Client Application, which is a **Multi Device Application** in delphi, and I have created a **DataSnap REST Server** Application that communicates directly to SQL Server 2012. The DataSnap App is well able to read data from SQL (as it should).

Now I would like to connect the Client App to the DataSnap App via the **FireDAC** Framework. Each time I enter the required parameters and test the connection (while the server is running), it tells me "***Socket Error #10061 Connection refused***".

Is there anything that I could be missing? I am using ***http*** protocol without authentication specifications.

Comment: Is the server running on the same host as the client application?  And I think we need some more information about the server configuration.  How did you test your server application anyway?  Are you sure it accepts connections?

Comment: The Server is running on the same host as the client. I used the DataSnap REST Application to create the server, assigned it a port - tested the port to see if it is free before creating it. I then used the FireDAC framework to create a connection with Sql Server 2012. I used the FDConnection component in the ServerContainer; specified the driver, database, server, user name and password, and then I tested the connection before creating it. It accepts the connection.

Comment: You say in your last comment 'It accepts the connection'.  So the connection works designtime but not at runtime?

Comment: It works at runtime as well. I am able to load data into the server app from sql

Comment: I disabled the firewall as well, and i still had the same problem

Comment: with connection, I don't mean Server App to database, but client app to server app.  Have you checked out this [article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application_and_FireDAC)

Comment: i can't get the connection between the Client app and the Server app right. I have set the Driver ID: DS, protocol: http, Server: localhost, DatasnapContext: datasnap/, and the Port number to the Server's port number. When I test the connection with these parameters, it gives me the message "Socket Error #10061 Connection refused".

Comment: I followed the article you placed - thank you, and when I incorporate the Client App in the same project group as the Server, I can no longer run it on mobile platforms; but only on the desktop. This pauses a problem because the Client App is a mobile app. I created the datasnap server as a Firemonkey app to make it compatible with the client app